# Angular 2 TypeScript: enableProdMode when bundling with JSPM

Tags: typescript, angular, production-environment, systemjs, jspm

I'm building an Angular 2 app and bundling it with SystemJS/JSPM.

During development I import the app in `index.html`:

```
<script src="jspm_packages/system.js"></script>
<script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>
<script src="systemjs.importapp.js"></script>
```

I bundle with:

```
jspm bundle-sfx app assets/js/myapp.sfx.min.js --minify --no-mangle --skip-source-maps
```

And have a version of `index.html` with

```
<script src="assets/js/myapp.sfx.min.js" defer></script>
```

replacing the three above.

My `main.ts` starting point looks like:

```
// CORE IMPORTS
import 'es6-shim';
import 'reflect-metadata';
import 'zone.js';
import 'zone.js/dist/zone';
import 'zone.js/dist/long-stack-trace-zone';
import 'rxjs';

// ADD ALL OPERATORS TO OBSERVABLES
import 'rxjs/Rx';

// APP INITIALISATION
import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform/browser';
import {enableProdMode} from 'angular2/core';
import {AppComponent} from './app.component';
import {ROUTER_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/router';

bootstrap(AppComponent, [
  ROUTER_PROVIDERS
]);
```

What I would like to do is call `enableProdMode()` only when I'm bundling with `jspm bundle-sfx`.

What would be the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found one solution to this: making an external JSON file, e.g. `environment.json`, in the same directory as my app's `main.ts` entry point, containing:

```
{
  'env': 'dev'
}
```

Then in `main.ts`:

```
import _environment from './environment.json!json';

if (_environment.env === 'dev') {
  console.log('Running in dev mode.')
}

if (_environment.env === 'prod') {
  console.log('Running in production mode.');
  enableProdMode();
}
```

This requires the SystemJS JSON plugin to be installed:

```
jspm install json
```

Then, in my build script, I change `env` to `prod` just before building the bundle, and back to `dev` afterwards, using [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/).